# Moving Stack Overflow Feed In Loop Chat

Tags: discussion, chat

Right now the stack overflow blog feeds into our stacks chat channel as messages, but they're big, rarely relevant, and drown out chat:

[image]

So I've moved them to the ticker in the top left, are people happy with keeping this change?

Comment: Definitely a good change.